# Bash: Execute a command in each directory with file my_suites.cfg?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to create a script which executes a command(similar to make command) in every directory which contains a file called `my_suites.cfg`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you expand your question to show what you already tried? Where are the directories located - directly beneath the "current" directory, or can they be deeply nested inside a directory tree?

Comment: There's no concrete pattern to how the directories are. But the file my_suites.cfg will be present in each directory. When I do this manually, I need to cd into a directory with such file to execute the make command which will generate a json file which I need to copy to a different location.

Comment: Is there any kind of ```root/master``` directory under which all subdirectories including those who possibly contain the file ```my_suites.cfg```  belong to?

Comment: Yes, it's a code repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your tag indicates `bash`, you can use the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/; do if [[ -f "$d/my_suites.cfg" ]]; then cd "$d"; make; cd -; fi; done
```

This will iterate over all directories and sub-directories of the current directory, check if a file `my_suites.cfg` exists, and if so, changes to that directory, calls `make`, and changes back to the original directory.

Comment: I've expanded the bash script that you have provided so that it will copy the generated files to a /debug folder. The necessary sub-folders are created for each file in the loop depending on the $d variable. I would like to concatenate all of the files that are stored in the /debug folder in their nested folder-structure. Is this command correct for such purpose if I'm standing in the /debug folder? 

cat **/my_file.json >my_file.json

Comment: @Phi-LongVu I think that requires further clarification that exceeds the scope of the comment section. I would recommend that you open another, follow-up question, and create a link to this question for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` to execute a command (example: pwd) with a working directory where the named file ist found:

```
find /path/to/repository -type f -name my_suites.cfg -execdir pwd \;
```

/path/to/repository can also be a relative path (even ".")

Answer (score 0):

So to generalize the question: You want to run a bash command on each file
that has a specific name, one at a time.

Assuming, that you are willing to use existing tools and not write
everything
from scratch by yourself, here are some ideas:

## TL;DR *(Too long, didn't read)*

If it doesn't matter whether the newest files are not recognized yet:

```bsh
$ mlocate --basename --regex "^my_suites.cfg$" \
| xargs dirname \
| xargs -d '\n' <command-to-run-on-the-file>
```

Else if efficiency is not so important (assuming, that we are searching
recursively in the home directory (`~`) only:

```bsh
$ find ~ -name "my_suites.cfg" -type f \
| xargs dirname \
| xargs -d '\n' <command-to-run-on-the-file>
```

---

## Full Version

### Finding the files

If the files you are looking for are scattered all over the system, you
should
care about effectiveness.

#### The fast(er) way

With some downsides

```bsh
$ mlocate --basename --regex "^my_suites.cfg$"
```

- `mlocate` looks up file paths in a database that is updated once a day for
  most distributions. So it may not recognize recently created or
  recently moved
  files. But because it looks into the database instead of going through the
  file system itself, it's search is very efficient.
- The `--basename` option specifies that we are looking for the direct
  name of
  the file, not including the path/directories of it.
- The `--regex` option enables regular expressions being allowed in the
  search
  pattern. (The `^` expects the string to start there and the `$`
  expects the
  string to end there.)

#### The "always up-to-date" way

```bsh
$ find / -name "my_suites.cfg" -type f
```

- `find` goes through basically every folder it can find and lists
  every file which is named my_suites.cfg. Because of that many
  reading-operations that it has to do, the more folders it searches
  the slower it gets.
- The `-name` option specifies, that my_suites.cfg is the **name** of
  the file,
  instead of i.e. a folder that contains the file that we are looking for.
- The `-type` option specifies, that we are looking for a **file**, not
  for a
  directory, symlink, socket or something.

### Running a custom command on each of the files

... that's what `xargs` is for

#### A simple example

```bsh
$ echo "some simple example" | xargs mkdir
$ # now there are three directories, named by the echoed words
$ ls
example  simple  some
```

#### Something more complex:

```bsh
$ echo "hello world" | xargs -d ' ' -I % echo 'Print a word: %'
Print a word: hello
Print a word: world
```

- `-d` option: specifies, which character delimits the arguments from each
  other (here: a space).
- `-I` option: All occurences of the given character (`%` in this example)
  will be replaced by the argument that came from the pipe (before `|`)

This is what happens in the above example:

1. `echo` prints "hello world" to the standard output (`stdout`).
2. The pipe (`|`) gives this value ("hello world") to the following command,
   which happens to be `xargs`.
3. `xargs` searches for occurences of the delimiter in the argument and
   splits
   the argument where it finds the delimiter.
4. `xargs` loops through the newly created arguments and runs the command
   with the argument value instead of `%`

### Further readings

- [Unix xargs](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/)
- [Regular Expressions: Tutorial](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)
- [locate man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate)
- this answer also lives on [hoschi-it.de](https://hoschi-it.de/2021/03/09/exec-a-command-for-each-specific-file/) (which is my personal webpage)

Comment: you still need to go from the filename `/foo/bar/my_suites.cfg` to running the command in `/foo/bar`

Comment: @ilkkachu right, thanks!